# Storing Attributes on XML in VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have created an XML with this general format and am having difficulties storing attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
-<Report>
    -<Class Name="ClassA">
        <Property Name="Property1" dType="Boolean">False</Property>
    </Class>
    -<Class Name="ClassB">
        -<Property Name="Property2" dType="SortedList`2" Value="String" Key="Int16">
            <SrtLstItm Key="1">94</SrtLstItm>
        </Property>
        <Property Name="Property3" dType="Int32">1</Property>
        -<Property Name="Property4" dType="List`1" Type="Product">
            <LstItm Name="Property4">LstItm1</LstItm>
            <LstItm Name="Property4">LstItm2</LstItm>
        </Property>
    </Class>
    -<Class Name="ClassC">
        <Property Name="Property5" dType="String">50.5</Property>
    </Class>
</Report>
```

What I am interested in doing is using XMLTextReader to store Class Name so as it is reading through the Properties it still has class information. I am currently using Select Case by NodeType:

```
Dim xrdr = New System.Xml.XmlTextReader(fileName)
Do While (xrdr.Read())
  Select Case xrdr.NodeType
    Case XmlNodeType.Element 'Display beginning of element.'
      Select Case xrdr.Name
        Case xrdr.Name = "Class"
          cls = xrdr.GetAttribute("Name")
        Case xrdr.Name = "Property"
          propertyName = xrdr.GetAttribute("Name")
        Case xrdr.Name = "SrtListItm"
          srtLstKey = xrdr.GetAttribute("Key")
      End Select
      If xrdr.HasAttributes Then 'If attributes exist'
        While xrdr.MoveToNextAttribute()
          ''Display attribute name and value.              
        End While
      End If
    Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.'
      vle = xrdr.ReadString
    Case XmlNodeType.EndElement 'Display end of element.'
  End Select
Loop
xrdr.Close()
```

I plan on using the code to update the public properties of each class with updated values given in the XML. Before this I had the XML so each property had a class attribute and the code would be able to read and update all properties that did not have children. I'm restructuring it to account for properties of the array type. Any help would be appreciated and thank you for your time.

Update: using the solution posted I came up with the following.
From the above code I was able to read in all non-array properties. Now I am trying to import the values from the children.

```
Dim xrdr = New System.Xml.XmlTextReader(fileName)
Do While (Not xrdr.EOF)
  xrdr.ReadToFollowing("Class")
  If (Not xrdr.EOF) Then
    Dim _class As XElement = XElement.ReadFrom(xrdr)
    Dim cls As String = _class.Attribute("Name")
    For Each _property As XElement In _class.Elements("Property")
      Dim propertyName As String = _property.Attribute("Name")
      fInfo = ps.GetType().GetField("_" & cls,
           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or
           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or
           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
      'Use the FieldInfo to retrieve the sub-class the matches the cls variable.'
        obj = fInfo.GetValue(object)'Object created before read'

      'Using reflection, get the PropertyInfo of the Property that matches'
      'the text in the nme variable.'
      pInfo = obj.GetType.GetProperty(propertyName)
      If pInfo Is Nothing Then

      Else
        Dim pInfoType = pInfo.PropertyType.Name

        If pInfoType = "SortedList`2" Then
          For Each _child As XElement In _property.Elements("SrtLstItm")
            Dim childName As String = _child.Attribute("Key")
            pInfo = obj.GetType.GetProperty(childName)
            tmpVal = CTypeDynamic(_child.Value, pInfo.PropertyType)
            pInfo.SetValue(obj, tmpVal, Nothing)
          Next
        ElseIf pInfoType = "List`1" Then
        ElseIf pInfoType = "Product" Then
        Else
          'Convert the value (vle) to the type of the Property to which
          'it will be assigned.  CTypeDynamic must be used so that the
          'type retrieved from pInfo can be used.
          tmpVal = CTypeDynamic(_property.Value, pInfo.PropertyType)
          'Use the PropertyInfo to set the value of the property
          'that matches nme. 
          pInfo.SetValue(obj, tmpVal, Nothing)
        End If

      End If

    Next _property

  End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a much simpler way of using XmlTextReader with linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim xrdr = New System.Xml.XmlTextReader(FILENAME)
        Do While (Not xrdr.EOF)
            xrdr.ReadToFollowing("Class")
            If (Not xrdr.EOF) Then
                Dim _class As XElement = XElement.ReadFrom(xrdr)
                Dim results = GetClass(_class)
            End If
        Loop

    End Sub
    Function GetClass(_class As XElement) As Object
        Return _class.DescendantsAndSelf().Select(Function(x) New With {
                 .name = x.Attribute("Name").Value,
                 .properties = x.Elements("Property").Select(Function(y) New With {
                        .name = CType(y.Attribute("Name"), String),
                        .dType = CType(y.Attribute("dType"), String),
                        .value = CType(y.Attribute("Value"), String),
                        .key = CType(y.Attribute("Key"), String),
                        .sortedLstItm = y.Elements("SrtLstItm").Select(Function(z) New With {
                                .key = CType(z.Attribute("Key"), String),
                                .value = Integer.Parse(z.Value)
                        }).ToList(),
                        .lstItms = y.Elements("LstItm").Select(Function(z) New With {
                            .name = CType(z.Attribute("Name"), String),
                            .value = z.Value
                        }).ToList()
                  }).ToList()
        }).FirstOrDefault()
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: I am a little familiar with linq. From your code I can get _property.value, but in the case for sorted lists and lists how do I get those multiple values?

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, I came up with 2 ways to walk the DOM. The first uses a XmlDocument, and the second uses the XmlTextReader. I put both into a sample that outputs information to a TextBox. I did it this way in case you find it easier to use the XmlDocument to track which level you are at. In either case, you would need to catch the start of each unique element (Class, Property, the Property children, etc) and use accordingly.

This is the single sub I created to parse your file:

```
Private Sub ReadXmlData(ByRef fileName As String)

  Dim cls As String = String.Empty
  Dim propertyName As String = String.Empty
  Dim srtLstKey As String = String.Empty
  Dim vle As String = String.Empty
  Dim counter As Integer = 0

  Dim output As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

  '
  '-- METHOD 1: XmlDocument --
  '

  'Notice how this one could benefit from recursive calls to a single function due to the nested child nodes.

  Dim xDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
  xDoc.Load(fileName)

  Dim node As XmlNode
  Dim child As XmlNode
  Dim child2 As XmlNode
  Dim attr As XmlAttribute
  counter = 1
  For Each node In xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
     output.AppendLine("#" & counter.ToString() & ": " & node.Name)
     For Each attr In node.Attributes
        output.AppendLine("Attribute [" & attr.Name & "] = " & attr.Value)
     Next
     If node.HasChildNodes Then
        For Each child In node.ChildNodes
           output.AppendLine("-- Child [" & child.Name & "] = " & child.Name)
           If child.InnerText.Length > 0 Then output.AppendLine("---- (Text): " & child.InnerText)
           If child.Attributes IsNot Nothing Then
              For Each attr In child.Attributes
                 output.AppendLine("---- Attribute [" & attr.Name & "] = " & attr.Value)
              Next
           End If
           If child.HasChildNodes Then
              For Each child2 In child.ChildNodes
                 output.AppendLine("------ Child [" & child2.Name & "] = " & child2.Name)
                 If child2.InnerText.Length > 0 Then output.AppendLine("------ (Text): " & child2.InnerText)
                 If child2.Attributes IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each attr In child2.Attributes
                       output.AppendLine("------ Attribute [" & attr.Name & "] = " & attr.Value)
                    Next
                 End If
              Next
           End If
        Next
     End If
     counter += 1
  Next
  output.Append("=", 30)
  output.AppendLine()

  '
  '-- METHOD 2: XmlTextReader --
  '

  Dim xrdr = New System.Xml.XmlTextReader(fileName)

  counter = 1
  Do While (xrdr.Read())
     If xrdr.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element Then
        output.Append("-", 20)
        output.Append(" " & counter.ToString() & " ")
        output.Append("-", 20)
        output.AppendLine()
        counter += 1
     End If
     output.AppendLine(xrdr.NodeType.ToString())
     Select Case xrdr.NodeType
        Case XmlNodeType.Element 'Display beginning of element.
           output.AppendLine("NODETYPE -- Name: " & xrdr.Name)
           Select Case xrdr.Name
              Case "Class"
                 cls = xrdr.GetAttribute("Name")
                 output.AppendLine("Class: " & cls)
              Case "Property"
                 propertyName = xrdr.GetAttribute("Name")
                 output.AppendLine("Property: " & propertyName)
              Case "SrtLstItm"
                 srtLstKey = xrdr.GetAttribute("Key")
                 output.AppendLine("SrtLstItm Key: " & srtLstKey)
              Case "LstItm"
                 output.AppendLine("LstItm: Name=" & xrdr.GetAttribute("Name"))
           End Select
           If xrdr.HasAttributes Then 'If attributes exist
              While xrdr.MoveToNextAttribute()
                 output.AppendLine("Attribute [" & xrdr.Name & "] = " & xrdr.Value)
              End While
           End If
        Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
           vle = xrdr.ReadString
           output.AppendLine("(Text): " & vle)
        Case XmlNodeType.EndElement 'Display end of element.
           output.Append("-", 10)
           output.Append(" [End Element] ")
           output.Append("-", 10)
           output.AppendLine()
     End Select
  Loop
  xrdr.Close()

  XmlOutput.Text = output.ToString()
End Sub
```

The output to XmlOutput looks like this. Ignore the syntax highlighting. I couldn't use blockquote because it was parsing various characters as markup.

```
#1: Class
Attribute [Name] = ClassA
-- Child [Property] = Property
---- (Text): False
---- Attribute [Name] = Property1
---- Attribute [dType] = Boolean
------ Child [#text] = #text
------ (Text): False
#2: Class
Attribute [Name] = ClassB
-- Child [Property] = Property
---- (Text): 94
---- Attribute [Name] = Property2
---- Attribute [dType] = SortedList`2
---- Attribute [Value] = String
---- Attribute [Key] = Int16
------ Child [SrtLstItm] = SrtLstItm
------ (Text): 94
------ Attribute [Key] = 1
-- Child [Property] = Property
---- (Text): 1
---- Attribute [Name] = Property3
---- Attribute [dType] = Int32
------ Child [#text] = #text
------ (Text): 1
-- Child [Property] = Property
---- (Text): LstItm1LstItm2
---- Attribute [Name] = Property4
---- Attribute [dType] = List`1
---- Attribute [Type] = Product
------ Child [LstItm] = LstItm
------ (Text): LstItm1
------ Attribute [Name] = Property4
------ Child [LstItm] = LstItm
------ (Text): LstItm2
------ Attribute [Name] = Property4
#3: Class
Attribute [Name] = ClassC
-- Child [Property] = Property
---- (Text): 50.5
---- Attribute [Name] = Property5
---- Attribute [dType] = String
------ Child [#text] = #text
------ (Text): 50.5
==============================
XmlDeclaration
Whitespace
-------------------- 1 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: Report
Whitespace
-------------------- 2 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: Class
Class: ClassA
Attribute [Name] = ClassA
Whitespace
-------------------- 3 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: Property
Property: Property1
Attribute [Name] = Property1
Attribute [dType] = Boolean
Text
(Text): False
Whitespace
EndElement
---------- [End Element] ----------
Whitespace
-------------------- 4 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: Class
Class: ClassB
Attribute [Name] = ClassB
Whitespace
-------------------- 5 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: Property
Property: Property2
Attribute [Name] = Property2
Attribute [dType] = SortedList`2
Attribute [Value] = String
Attribute [Key] = Int16
Whitespace
-------------------- 6 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: SrtLstItm
SrtLstItm Key: 1
Attribute [Key] = 1
Text
(Text): 94
Whitespace
EndElement
---------- [End Element] ----------
Whitespace
-------------------- 7 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: Property
Property: Property3
Attribute [Name] = Property3
Attribute [dType] = Int32
Text
(Text): 1
Whitespace
-------------------- 8 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: Property
Property: Property4
Attribute [Name] = Property4
Attribute [dType] = List`1
Attribute [Type] = Product
Whitespace
-------------------- 9 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: LstItm
LstItm: Name=Property4
Attribute [Name] = Property4
Text
(Text): LstItm1
Whitespace
-------------------- 10 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: LstItm
LstItm: Name=Property4
Attribute [Name] = Property4
Text
(Text): LstItm2
Whitespace
EndElement
---------- [End Element] ----------
Whitespace
EndElement
---------- [End Element] ----------
Whitespace
-------------------- 11 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: Class
Class: ClassC
Attribute [Name] = ClassC
Whitespace
-------------------- 12 --------------------
Element
NODETYPE -- Name: Property
Property: Property5
Attribute [Name] = Property5
Attribute [dType] = String
Text
(Text): 50.5
Whitespace
EndElement
---------- [End Element] ----------
Whitespace
EndElement
---------- [End Element] ----------
```

Note that InnerText may not always be wanted, such as with the Property that has LstItm properties. But, this should get you started on finding what you need.

Comment: Thank you Chris. With Method 2 I am still not getting a value for cls.

Comment: @MatthewKruse - cls is populating fine. Here's where I have it outputting:

`output.AppendLine("Class: " & cls)`

So, in the output, it's right here:

> NODETYPE -- Name: Class
> Attribute [Name] = **ClassB**

Additional attributes are in the `If xrdr.HasAttributes...` block.

Comment: Sorry. Correction.

Hmm. You're right. It's pulling as part of the `If xrdr.HasAttributes` line. Maybe you have to make the `xrdr.MoveToNextAttribute()` call before trying to get it. The reader doesn't work the same as a document.

Comment: Got it. I'm going to edit my response accordingly. Your Case statements were doing comparisons.

Comment: I noticed it's not getting the "Key" attribute for "SrtLstItm" or "LstItm". The first one is because the Element is "SrtLstItm", but it's checking for "SrtListItm" (notice the "i" in List). For "LstItm", the case isn't being handled, so it's just pulling the details as normal as you can see under lines 9 and 10.

Comment: @MatthewKruse I fixed the case for the SrtLstItm and added in one for LstItm for you to see.

Comment: for Method 2 is xrdr.MoveToNextAttribute needed? Will the Do While (xrdr.Read()) read all attributes?

Comment: `xrdr.Read()` will read the nodes/elements, but it won't go through the attributes. If you notice, the first thing my example does is output the NodeType name. None of them are "Attribute". Granted, it's going through them within the Case statement, so there wouldn't be any. But, I commented out the While block and added a check for Attribute BEFORE the check for Element. It still didn't see them. The `xrdr.Read()` found: XmlDeclaration, Whitespace, each Element (Report, Class, Property, SrtLstItm, LstItm), Text, and EndElement. So, that traversal would be needed.